# How to add connection string dynamically in web.config

Tags: asp.net

I have to create one application which will add connection string in web.config when user clicks on some control.
actually it runs fine,
But now together with it i have to run one SQL script which will create new database. 
for that i have write following code..
now it gives me error as

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public partial class connectionString : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
           // System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            var section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;
            section.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings(txtNAme.Text, txtNAme.Text, "System.Data.SqlClient"));
            config.Save();

            string sqlConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=ccwebgrity;Data Source=SURAJIT\SQLEXPRESS";
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"G:\AAA\SCRIPT.sql");
            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
            file.OpenText().Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the connection string in web.config

```
     <ConnectionStrings>
 <add name="student" connectionString="Server=student;Max Pool Size=300;Initial Catalog=studentDB;User ID=student;Password=st123dent;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
     </Connectionstrings>
```

Configuration is read only so you can not do it in obvious way like

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["student"].ConnectionString = "new value";
```